# How to published already localised content on wordpress.org website?

Tags: wordpress, localization, translation, blogs, elementor

I’ve a blog posts website which has got all the content in "English" language till now.

- I need to publish same set of posts in EU language and they are already localized manually ( without any plugin etc )

Please clarify how can I include these blog posts under their respective language which user can choose from home screen and see the localized blog posts.

Googling is showing only localization with some plugin which I don’t need.